# calling javascript from Dart

Tags: javascript, dart

i was able to fire off an alert message from dart, but couldn't figure out how to call a function I wrote in another js file from dart.  This would have been a great selling point if it was straight forward.  I did see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716004/will-dart-support-the-use-of-existing-javascript-libraries), which got me started, but i feel there must be a way, so please share the love if you figured it out.

Here's what I've done:

1. Add this to yaml file:

   dependencies:
     js:
       hosted: js
2. Add import statement to top of dart file: import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;
3. Add this bit of code to show alert message

   js.scoped(() {
             js.context.alert("jump for joy!");
            });
4. Here's the part which I think should work but doesn't: given that I have a javascript function doSomething(), I should be able to call

   js.context.doSomething();

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First add the [js package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js) as dependency in your `pubspec.yaml` :

```yaml
dependencies:
  js: any
```

Then you can use your own js function `myFunc()` like that :

```dart
import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;

main() {
  js.context.myFunc();
}
```

`js.context` is an alias to javascript `window`.

See [Using JavaScript from Dart: The js Library](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/js-dart-interop/) for more details.

Comment: And when importing, we should specify the prefix for the above code to work: `import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;`

Comment: what is js:0.0.13 for and  how is that different from js: any

Comment: The string "any" allows any version ( see [Version constraints](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/pubspec.html#version-constraints) ). I put `0.0.13` to ensure the last available version is used.

Comment: is js.scoped still being used?

Comment: `js.scoped` has been removed since `package:js` is baked with `dart:js`.

Comment: js.context does not exist anymore

Answer (score 12):

Maybe my answer will be worth it for somebody, so that's why I'm posting a simple JS function call from Dart.

1. Add the [`js`](https://pub.dev/packages/js) package dependency:

   ```yaml
   dependencies:
     js: any
   ```
2. Create a JS file, let's say `example.js`:

   ```js
   function test() {
     return 12+20;
   }
   ```
3. Add the `example.js` above inside `index.html` with the `<script src="...">` tag.
4. Interop the function above from JS to Dart:

   ```dart
   @JS()
   library t;

   import 'package:js/js.dart';

   @JS()
   external int Test();

   class MyOwn {
     int get value => Test();
   }
   ```
5. And, in AngularDart's TODOLIST — which is default component available —:

   ```dart
   @override
   Future<Null> ngOnInit() async => print(MyOwn().value);
   ```

Comment: What do I do if the JS I want to call is an NPM package? Eg., https://github.com/polkadot-js/extension