# Calling my JavaScript from Dart

Tags: javascript, dart, call, dart-editor

This should be simple, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around it.

So I have my dartFile.dart and then I have my javaScriptFile.js. How do I link these two so that I can call JavaScript functions declared in my javaScriptFile.js from my dartFile.dart?

I tried to follow the explanation provided in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845528/calling-javascript-from-dart), but I guess it was too vague for me :/

Edit: Here's what I tried:

In my javaScriptFile.js, there is nothing but this simple function:

```
function myFunction() {
  return 4;
}
```

In my dartFile.dart, there is only this blob of code:

```
import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;

void main() {
  print(js.context.myFunction());
}
```

Following the instructions in the post I mentioned, I added dependencies for js in the pubspec.yaml file.
Basically I'm exactly where the asker of the original question was - I can call basic JavaScript functions like alert, but wehn I try to call my function declared in the javaScriptFile.js, I get a 'NoSuchMethodError'

Comment: Your question should be much more specific about what you try to accomplish and show code that demonstrates what you have tried, and what error you got.

Comment: You make a fine point. I tried to keep it simple, but perhaps I should have been more specific. Is it better now?

Comment: Why do you need JS if you already can use Dart?

Comment: Heh, only now that you asked I realized how this must look :D I need to use external libraries written in JavaScript (by someone else of course). I used my own JavaScript file here in this example purely for learning purposes - in order to simplify things as much as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do it like this:

1. Make sure you include JS before .dart files or make sure all JS files are loaded before running Scripts from Dart
2. Contents of the dart file:

---

```
import 'dart:js';

void main() {
  var ret = context.callMethod('myFunction', ['a', 'b']);
  var inst = new JsObject(context['someClass'], ['instance']); 
  print(inst);
}
```

1. my JS File:

---

```
function myFunction() {
  console.log(arguments);
}

function someClass(a) {
  this.a = a;
}
```

---

This should give you output like

```
[object Arguments] // from console.log
[object Object]    // from print()
```

Regards,
Robert

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly now! I was puzzled by the "Make sure you include JS before .dart files" for a second, but then I realized you meant the <script src="JavaScriptFile.js"></script> line in the .html file. (And thus, I'm writtin this comment in case anyone else get stuck where I did)