# Embedding a Youtube video in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, youtube, flutter-web

Is it possible to embed a Youtube video in a Flutter web page? I tried the following code to have a Youtube embedded in my Flutter website, but nothing appears on the page without any error message.

```
import 'package:flutter_html_view/flutter_html_view.dart';

Container(child: HtmlView(data: """
          <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xMzkWfIR9Pk" width="560" height="315"></iframe>
          """)),
```

Also tried the solution recommended here ([WebView in Flutter Web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58150503/webview-in-flutter-web)) but that doesn't work either.

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui

//ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
  ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      'hello-world-html',
      (int viewId) => html.IFrameElement()
        ..width = '640'
        ..height = '360'
        ..src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/IyFZznAk69U'
        ..style.border = 'none');
```

Comment: I'm getting close.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59890992/embedded-youtube-video-widget-disappears-while-a-web-page-created-by-flutter-fo

Answer (score 3):

I used to package called [flutter_html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html)
But this gave me some scrolling issues.

```
Html(
    data: '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/D_mCZlQZg9Y" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should go like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61977369/9937309)

```
  import 'dart:html' as html;
  import 'dart:js' as js;
  import 'dart:ui' as ui;

  String viewID = "your-view-id";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
        viewID,
            (int id) => html.IFrameElement()
          ..width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width.toString()
          ..height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height.toString()
          ..src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/IyFZznAk69U'
          ..style.border = 'none');

    return SizedBox(
      height: 500,
      child: HtmlElementView(
        viewType: viewID,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: ui.platformViewRegistry has an error: Try correcting the prefix or importing the library that defines 'platformViewRegistry'.dartundefined_prefixed_name

Comment: The name 'platformViewRegistry' is being referenced through the prefix 'ui', but it isn't defined in any of the libraries imported using that prefix.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [youtube_player_iframe](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_iframe)

```
YoutubePlayerController _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
    initialVideoId: 'K18cpp_-gP8',
    params: YoutubePlayerParams(
        playlist: ['nPt8bK2gbaU', 'gQDByCdjUXw'], // Defining custom playlist
        startAt: Duration(seconds: 30),
        showControls: true,
        showFullscreenButton: true,
    ),
);

YoutubePlayerIFrame(
    controller: _controller,
    aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
),
```

Answer (score 0):

[ext_video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/ext_video_player) supports Android, iOS and web for YouTube. You can try running sample code from ext_video_player [repo](https://github.com/ponnamkarthik/ext_video_player).

I tested with different browsers of different OS. Android, Mac, Windows browsers are working fine with ext_video_player. But it's not playing with iOS browser.

[image]

Comment: I tried to use the repo you indicated. Doesn't work on web. It's just stuck on that linear progress widget rather than loading the vid.

Answer (score 0):

There are, at least, two solutions:

a) video_player package now works fine in the three main platforms: android, ios and web

b) This article explains a good way to embed video source in a flutter web widget, even when the article is for local files, the final procedure works fine for web sources, like youtube, too: https://vermahitesh.medium.com/play-local-video-on-flutter-web-d757bab0141c