# Embed a web page as a Widget inside Flutter for Web application (similar to iframe)

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm basically looking for a widget that works on Flutter for Web that allows you to embed a website as a widget inside an application.

This relates to [Embedded Youtube video widget disappears while the web page (created by Flutter for Web) is scrolled up or down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59890992/embedded-youtube-video-widget-disappears-while-the-web-page-created-by-flutter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use [IFrameElement](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-html/IFrameElement-class.html).

[here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-web-and-iframe-f26399aa1e2a) you can find a good explanation of how to do it.