# Run local HTML, CSS & JS in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

So I’m trying to run local HTML, JS, CSS from flutter Web.

I figured out that you usually could use flutter Web View plus, but it isn’t compatible with Web.

I also figured out that it isn’t a big problem showing plain HTML in Flutter Web (through WebView_Web). But I can’t figure out how to depict HTML code & additionally JS in Flutter Web.

How could I achieve wished behavior or does somebody have a link to a tutorial/video that could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For wrapping **JS** libraries with **HTML** you can use `IFrame` approach that is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60276170/use-js-library-in-flutter-web)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to run the **web server** by the command below where `port` property you can customize

```
flutter run -d web-server --web-port 8080
```

After you need to open in your browser the `index.html` file from your `build/web` folder and after that just change the port number to the same one that you specified before

[image]

Comment: But how can I have for example in a Container widget that is in the original Flutter html an additional local HTML file

Comment: Then I totally don't understand what do you want to achieve

Comment: I want to integrate Paypals Buttons from the PayPal Sdk