# How to use JS library in Flutter Web App?

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

I am trying to port an existing web app into flutter.
The existing web app uses jQuery library and several other JS libraries.
Is there any way to use JS libraries in flutter app? 
I couldn't find any documentation on the same.

Comment: Check the following stackoverflow question
[will-dart-support-the-use-of-existing-javascript-libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716004/will-dart-support-the-use-of-existing-javascript-libraries)

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this function by [writing custom platform-specific code](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels).

> This guide describes how to write custom platform-specific code. Some
> platform-specific functionality is available through existing
> packages; see [using packages](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages).

> **Note:** The information in this page is valid for most platforms, but
> platform-specific code for the web generally uses [JS
> interoperability](https://dart.dev/web/js-interop) or the [dart:html
> library](https://api.dart.dev/dart-html/dart-html-library.html)
> instead.